# Treasure Hunt Math or Code Clue

Tags: calculus

I'm playing [CreasureQuest](https://www.creasurequest.co) and one of the clues is the following:

```
 2357131719
-11238132134
```

Apparently, it's not just a subtraction, but something else.

I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction!

Thank you

Comment: This would be better on puzzling.se

Answer (score 2):

The first line: $2,3,5,7,13,17,19$ are seven of the first eight primes; $11$ is missing.

The second line: $1,1,2,3,8,13,21,34$ are eight of the first nine Fibonacci numbers; $5$ is missing.

I'm not sure how one subtracts "missing $5$" from "missing $11$", but perhaps the intended answer is $6$.